# Pandoc template variables within markdown file, not using yaml frontmatter

Tags: pandoc, markdown

I know I can use yaml front matter within a markdown file in order to define variables to be used in pandoc templates to generate latex. However is it possible to define those variables in the body of a markdown file?

like `$body$` would be the template tag for the markdown body, so if i could tag a list item in the markdown body to do: `$for(body.listtag)$ something $endfor$`

Comment: No, that is not possible (and also makes little sense).  You can set document variables only in the YAML Metadata block and on the command line.